# Help with differential topology exercise

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to solve a problem from Chapter 5 ("Degrees, Intersection Numbers and the Euler characteristic") of Hirsch's book "Differential topology". It goes like this:

" Let $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be real polynomials in $n\geq 2$ variables. Write $f_k=h_k + r_k$ where $h_k$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d_k\geq 2$ and $r_k$ has smaller degree. Assume that $x=(0,\dots,0)$ is the only solution to $h_1(x)=\dots=h_n(x)=0$. Assume also that $\det(\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_j}(x))\neq 0$ at all nonzero $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then the system of equations $f_1=\dots=f_n=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Hint: Use the previous exercise."

I have done the previous exercise. It states that if $f: U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^n}$ is a proper $\mathcal{C}^1$ map such that $\det(Df_x)$ does not change sign outside some compact set (and is not identically zero), then $f$ is surjective.

I am not looking for a solution to the exercise, but a good hint on how to use this lemma would be really appreciated.

I have tried to properly modify the morphism $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$ ( and $h$ ) into a proper one but didn't succeed.

Comment: But I'm confused. Aren't polynomial maps proper?

Comment: No, if you take $f(x,y)=x-y$ then the preimage of zero is not compact.

Comment: Right. I was being dopey. :) I never noticed this exercise in Hirsch. I'll have to ponder.

Comment: Since $h_k$ is the highest part degree, then you can reduce the large behaviour of $f$ to that of $h$. For example, you want to show that $f$ is proper, then you may try to show that $h$ is proper, that is, $h^{-1}(B_R)$ is bounded. Since the only solution to $h(x)=0$ is $x=0$, by compactness of the sphere and continuity of $|h|$ you have that $|h|>\delta>0$ on the sphere, or $|h(x/|x|)|^2=\sum |h_k(x)|^2/|x|^{2d_k}\ge \delta^2$, so for $|x|\ge 1$ in $h^{-1}(B_R)$ you have $|x|^{\min d_k}\delta\le R$, so  $h^{-1}(B_R)$ is bounded. Check details, I may be wrong.

Comment: The thing that happens when a multivariable polynomial $P(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ is not proper is that the zero set $P = 0$ is a noncompact hypersurface, so taking a sequence of points $p_n$ along that hypersurface to infinity $0 = P(p_n) \not \to \infty$. So I think for the sake of contradiction you should assume $f = (f_1, \cdots, f_n)$ does not have any zeroes and try to prove it is proper. user90189's comment about properness of $h$ is probably relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thank you for the very useful comments.

The hint of user90189 on how to prove that $h$ is proper works. With a very similar argument you can prove that $f$ is also proper, so the degree of these functions is well defined.

If you apply the lemma to $h$ and use the proper homotopy $H(x,t)=h(x)+tr(x)$ to show that $f$ and $h$ have the same degree, you get that the degree of $f$ is not equal to zero, so it must be surjective.